# Pass variable to modal in ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have some code that receives a variable `msg` which I'd like to somehow pass to my modal. I'm using flask and tried to use jinja syntax but couldn't figure how, js string interpolation doesn't seem to work either. How can I pass the `msg` variable into `("#$Sub_Fail-HERE").modal("show")`

```
$.ajax({
          url: "{{url_for('mail_submit')}}",
          type: "POST",
          data: mail,
          success: function(msg){
              $("#Sub_Success").modal("show");},
          error: function(msg){
              $("#Sub_Fail-${msg}").modal("show");}
          });
```

Comment: You have to use backticks to substitute a variable like that.

Comment: @Barmar do you mean ```$(`#Sub_Fail-${msg}`).modal("show")?```

Comment: Yes, that's how you use template literals.

Comment: And for the success I suspect you want to put `msg` into a text element of the modal DIV.